# explain what happened (C program)

Tags: java, c, memory, operating-system, computer-science

Assume that a system has a 64-bit virtual address with an 8-kb page size. Write a C- program 
that is passed a virtual address (in decimal) on the command line and have it output the page 
number and offset for the given address. As an example, your program would run as follows:
./a.out 8219986
The program would output:
The address 8219986 contains:
Page number: 1003
Offset = 3410
All computation must be done in binary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long long int MappedAdress = atoll(argv[1]);
    unsigned long long int page = MappedAdress;
    unsigned long long int offset = MappedAdress;
    //print long long address
    printf("The MappedAdress %llu contains:\n",MappedAdress);
    //shift to right 13 bit to retrive pages, then print
    page = page >> 13;
    printf("Page Number : %llu\n",page);
    //since it's 64-bit opr. Add offset AND 1FFF , 
    offset = offset & 0x1FFF;
    //print the offset
    printf("Offset = %llu\n\n",offset);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what just happened here ? and what to shall I do to write such a program but in Java as long as I have no background in C language?

Comment: There's nothing fancy going on in that code. If you don't know C at all, pick up a book. As for translating to Java: please first at least try to implement this yourself. Show the Java code you have if you're stuck.

Comment: Look up what the >> and '&' operators do in C, and what '13' has in common with '8-kb', or 8192.  You should then be able to complete your homework.  Hint - the operators are much the same in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain to me what just happened here ?

Roughly speaking, you converted an address 64 bit virtual address to a virtual page number and an offset, using the right-shift operator (`>>`) and the bitwise AND operator (`&`).

> And what to shall I do to write such a program but in Java as long as I have no background in C language?

What you should do is to read your Java textbook or lecture notes to find out about the `>>` and `&` operators (for integer operands), and what they do.  Then write the equivalent code in Java.

HINTS:

1. The `>>` and bitwise `&` operators mean pretty much the same thing in C and Java.
2. You should probably also read the lecture notes where your lecturer explained about virtual addresses and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

LEt's go back to the problem statement: given a 64-bit number that represents a byte address on a computer that has 8K size pages, return the page number and offset for that address.

That simply means that you take number / 8K to get the page address and the remainder is tie offset.  Of course, that can often be computed faster by using a right shift to get the page number and a mask to get the offset (but do handle leading "1" bit in the 64-bit number).

You don't need the C program to figure out how to break a 64 bit number into the two desired pieces.